# GAE ndb query excluding entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to write an ndb query which excludes a particular entity, identified by its id, from the result set.

I have tried the following:

```
result = Entity.query(Entity.key.id() != 'entity-id', *some other condition*).fetch()
```

The Entity.key.id() != 'entity-id' bit throws an error. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its possible to query exclude on key, you have a simple workaround to remove the result from the final results.

But if it worked the syntax should be something like this:

```
result = Entity.query(Entity.key != ndb.Key(Entity, id), *some other condition*).fetch()
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I believe you have to build the Key object from the kind and the ID using the from_path() Key method. Also, to reference an entity's key you need to use the `__key__` syntax, see my answer.

Comment: @HorseloverFat from_path() and Key() are the basically the same.

Comment: I do not find them to be the same in the db API. If I replace `.Key.from_path` in my answer with `.Key`  I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to exclude a particular entity based on its id using the db API (and I presume the ndb API with some minor alterations). The following syntax works for me using the db API. It builds a query with results that exclude the id in the `id_to_retrieve` variable:

```
id_to_retrieve = 123456
query = Entity.all() 
query.filter('__key__ !=',  db.Key.from_path('Entity', id_to_retrieve))
query.fetch(None)
```

Comment: You are using the db API not the ndb API.

Comment: Good point. I didn't notice it was an ndb question. I'll update the answer.